# Where can I find a component similar to Mini IDE or Script Editor for C#

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I could find only [it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScriptEditorCtrl.aspx) but it is too outdated. I would like to find a component for C# 4

Answer (score 1):

[Snippet compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)? - But I don't think it supports C# 4.0

Answer (score 0):

ScintillaNET

a .NET wrapper for Scintilla

[image]

From the HP:

> ScintillaNET is a powerful text editing control for Windows® Forms applications and a managed wrapper around the versatile Scintilla component. Created with the developer in mind, the ScintillaNET API makes it simple to add advanced text editing and syntax highlighting to your application or IDE. In addition ScintillaNET adds features not found in other Scintilla wrappers such as Visual Studio® style code snippets, integrated find and replace dialogs, true regular expression searches, multiple key-command bindings, and back/forward document navigation.

http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

For editing, http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx